# Can someone explain what happens to this page in the doc?

Tags: support, documentation, google-chrome, browser-support

When I go to this link https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays my browser freezes and I can't even kill the page.

Browser : Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 m 
Os : Windows 10

I've tried deleting the cache, still the same problem, INFINIT LOAD and I can't scroll in the page

Comment: No repro for me. You need to provide more details, including OS and browser version number.

Comment: I have infinite load at this page !! only this page,

Comment: I'm on chrome too, no problem for me.  What version?

Comment: I remember Shog talking about something similar on another page... in a comment, so I can't search for it.

Comment: Have you tried updating? I'm on v52.0.2743.82 (latest) and also Windows 10

Comment: I'll try update, but it's strange, this only happen when I go to this specific url !!

Comment: I've updated to the last version of Chrome and still the same Issue.